# Can I upgrade plugins via FTP?

Tags: plugins, updates, ftp

I'm having some trouble upgrading my plguins through the Dashboard, If i upgrade plugins manually via FTP, will i lose any info from plugins like statpress and all in one seo?

Comment: I removed the `wordpress.com` tag as it didn't seem to be appropriate to this question.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: yes you can upgrade your plugins via FTP.

1. Download the new version of the plugin.
2. Disable the plugin you are about to update.
3. Upload files over the top of the plugin.
4. Re-enable plugin

If the plugin is written well stats, settings and options should remain intact. As Rarst has already mentioned the automated upgrader just overwites files.

The reason for disabling the plugin first before upgrading is to stop regular site visitors running the plugin while files are being uploaded. If a plugin is run with only half of the correct files in place things can go wrong such as errors popping up and settings getting corrupt. Hence why you should disable the plugin first. When I say disable I do not mean delete.

Answer (score 2):

It should work just fine, plugin options should (and usually are) stored in database.

Automatic upgrade doesn't do much other than overwriting files.

Comment: Sorry Rarst,Am Using wp E-Commerce Plugin,while i update the Latest plugin,it shows Error on Database.After that it won't work.so depends upon the plugin's we can update...Must need to see the plugin-Notifications...

Comment: @Ramkumar It may have not been fully copied over.

Comment: @NoBugs, You replied to too old comment. :) anyhow there is a chance for that.